# Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (8.1.0)

Tags: mysql-workbench

Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (8.1.0).

A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.

MySQL Workbench is developed and tested for MySQL Server versions 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0

I was trying to run a command but it's showing error

Comment: the actual version is still the one from 8.0.34 and wasn't updated till now. 
You can still used it. i didn't noticed any problems

Comment: Could use some code or what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: 8.0.34 version is working perfectly now. thanks